# VS 2017 No parameterless constructor defined for this object

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have made a project base on .net core 2 in VS 2017. When I want to create a new controller with using entity framework I've got an error message :

> There was an error running the selected code generator:
>   No parameterless constructor defined for this object

Here is my Model:

```
public class Country : Entity<int>
{
    public Country()
    {

    }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(100)]
    [Display(Name = "Country Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual IEnumerable<Person> Persons { get; set; }
}
```

How should I troubleshoot this issue?

**UPDATE:**
Here is my `Entity` class:

```
public abstract class BaseEntity { 

}

public abstract class Entity<T> : BaseEntity, IEntity<T> 
{
    public virtual T Id { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What is `Entity`, and does it have a default (parameterless) constructor?

Comment: I have updated my question, please see it again.

Comment: Put a default parameterless constructor in BaseEntity and Entity<T>

Comment: @Mardoxx It doesn't have any effect, I still get the same error.

Comment: How you are creating the controller?

Comment: @Ali I right click on controller folder and select add new controller, then I choose MVC Controller with views, using Entity Framework

Comment: Could you update the question and include the generated code for the controller?

Comment: you're probably trying to instantiate a class with no default constructor

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same issue, and i realized it has nothing to do with the parameterless constructor, you are missing the Id property, just add

```
public string Id {get; set;}
```

to the model and you should be fine.